# Why does "SingleOrDefault" return null on second execution when there is data in DB?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 4.5 site using EF.  I have code that checks if a record in the DB exists, and if it doesn't it creates a new record. As a result of a problem in my code which I've subsequently fixed I was calling this code twice within a fraction of a second.  The result was that a duplicate record was created.  Here is my code:

```
    Word wordToUpdate = context.Words.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Label == word);
    if (wordToUpdate == null) // word doesn't exist yet so make a new one
    {
      Word w = new Word() { 
      // add new word stuff here   
      };
      context.Words.Add(w);
    }
    else 
    {
      // word already exists so just add stuff to existing entry
      wordToUpdate.AnnotationGroups.Add(ag);  
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
```

If the word doesn't already exist in the DB it is added twice.  Here are the timestamps from the duplicate records:

> ```
> CreatedOn
> 2014-03-11 06:52:35.743
> 2014-03-11 06:52:50.637
> ```

I've stepped through the code while watching the DB records and the new record is added during the first execution, so:

1. Why is `context.Words.SingleOrDefault()` returning null on the second execution when there is a matching record in the DB?
2. Duplicate records should never exist in this table.  How can I improve my code to make sure it is impossible for that to happen?

**EDIT**

Let me add a few details I've observed while debugging this with a breakpoint at the beginning of the code snippet above:

1. The first time it's called everything works as expected - since it's a new word `wordToUpdate` is null and a new word is added.
2. I stopped the code at `context.SaveChanges()` and checked the DB - a new row shows up with the new word added
3. The next call (this is an AJAX call from an Ajax.ActionLink link) fires with the same word
4. `wordToUpdate` returns null even though DB already contains that word and thus a duplicate entry for that word is added (I'm not using the word as the primary key and I'd rather handle this in code instead of trying the handle errors thrown from the DB)
5. When `context.SaveChanges` is called again another row is add to the DB

So my question is since this call is coming from the same client is the code actually being executed synchronously?  The way it steps through the code in debugging seems to suggest this, but this is where my knowledge of ASP.NET gets a little fuzzy.

Comment: If you don't want duplicate rows in the database, make sure that the database knows that. Apply a `unique` constraint against the column(s) that should be unique and you'll at least know that duff data can't get in there (and, hopefully, code will blow up when it tries to add such a duplicate and give you a good stack trace so you can identify how it's happening)

Comment: I know where it's happening - the code above is what's doing it because the SingleOrDefault query is incorrectly returning null.  Adding the unique constraint just throws a DbUpdateException when the code executes again.  Is the only solution to rely on the DB because I can't trust the linq query to return an accurate result?

Comment: That's not "a fraction of a second". The timestamps are 15s apart! I can't imagine that `SingleOrDefault` returns null when there is a record in the database and everything runs synchronously. `SingleOrDefault` *always* queries the database. Are you sure there are no case differences or leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: Maybe it's possible for wordToUpdate.AnnotationGroups.Add(ag) to take 15 seconds? The changes are only saved after that call.

Comment: is your code executed inside a transaction? Transaction isolation could explain what you see. Execute a query from SQL Management Studio to see if you get different results to the linq query

Comment: About the time, er, yes, sorry - 15 seconds in this case.  If I don't stop the code in debugging it's a fraction of a second...

Comment: No, it's not executed inside a transaction.  If I understand what you're asking, the database was created via EF code first and I haven't added any custom SQL queries.

Comment: You might need to add some more information about how the `context` is being set up (if it's not just created in the line above where your code sample starts)

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. SingleOrDefault returns null the second time around when a record already exists. I can't figure out whats causing his.

Comment: did anyone solve this? I am experiencing the same issue. when server is running the linq query works fine first time around, but the 2nd time called it returns null

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is with the assertion you are using: `w => w.Label == word`.

If you are comparing objects, even though they might have same contents, `==` just compares if they have the same memory address, which is the default implementation. You should override Equals in the Word class so the behavior compares key values or something like that.

Comment: I suspect that `public string Word.Label {get;set;`. Can't really see any other way of doing this in EF, in which case == should work due to a combination of how EF works and how .net string interning works.